# .net page design with complicated Ajax relationship

Tags: asp.net, ajax, web

I am creating a .net website in c#.

The master page contains a fixed footer bar from which you can display 'bookmarks'. I also have a remove function for each bookmark.

Some aspx pages may have a add bookmark/remove bookmark function (a button control) on them.

I use update panels throughout so button controls are always encapsulated by one.

If I add/remove a bookmark from an aspx page, I can trigger an update to the fixed footer panel. A delegate event is triggered in the aspx page which calls a method on the master page to update the fixed footer panel, so everything is sync'd dynamically.

It doesn't seem possible to do the same the other way around. If i remove a bookmark from the fixed footer, I would need to know if the current aspx page was displaying a bookmark control. Pretty much impossible I would have thought, but I'm open to suggestions.

With that in mind the question really is does anyone have a technique that they use to deal with these scenarios, such as calling a full page update or something similar, or is it a case of doing nothing until the next page load/postback?

Thanks in advance.